# Assessing impact of concurrent interventions on time series data

Tags: time-series, mixed-model, multivariate-analysis, bayesian-network, intervention-analysis

I am hoping to assess which interventions create the most change in multiple response variables.

What makes this problem more complicated than typical intervention analysis is the concurrent nature of multiple interventions. I.e., in one subject, multiple interventions may occur simultaneously and at different time intervals than in other subjects. As a result it's not easy for me to aggregate on a population level marking "before" and "after" periods for each intervention, and additional challenge comes while assessing which intervention amongst simultaneous interventions makes the biggest impact.

In my case, data is recorded in monthly intervals (so Response 1 and Response 2 indicate the monthly level of a given statistic), and once the intervention occurs it can be said permanently alter the subject.

```
Dummy data (Int. A, B, ... refer to different Interventions):
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Subject   Time   Int. A   Int. B   Int. C   Int. D   Response 1   Response 2
   1        1       0        0        0        0         1            3
   1        2       0        0        1        0         2            4
   1        3       1        0        1        0         3            6
   1        4       1        0        1        0         2            7
   2        1       0        0        0        1         3            0
   2        2       0        0        0        1         3            0
   2        3       0        0        0        1         3            0
   2        4       0        1        0        1         6            5
   2        5       0        1        1        1         6            4
   2        6       1        1        1        1         6            4
   3        1       0        0        0        0         1            3
   3        2       0        0        0        0         1            3
   3        3       1        0        0        1         1            7
   3        4       1        0        0        1         1            7
   3        5       1        1        1        1         6            7
```

So the main issue is how to best "disentagle" the various interventions given how they overlap and occur at different time periods for each subject (some not occuring at all) in order to assess the impact of each intervention on the response variables.

As there is between-subject variation, one idea that came to mind was to create a Mixed-Effects model, modelling each response variable separately (although the response vars. may be correlated) by creating random effects for each subject and other traits (eg sex) and fixed effects for time and each intervention, but I am unsure if this will capture the complexity of the problem and if it's appropriate for time series data.

Another method that appealed to me is to represen this system with a Bayesian Dynamic Network, but I ultimately am not sure if this is appropriate, as once an intervention occurs we know that the variable representing it will not change states. Additionally, I believe such a system would be useful in generating predictions, but as I am unfamiliar with BDNs I do not know if I would be able to gather information to quantify the level that e.g. Int. A effects Response 1.

Another idea is some kind of scheme of pairwise t-test (ie int. A&B vs A vs A&C ...) but as there are dozens of interventions available I feel like it would be difficult to ultimately decipher some sort of hierarchy for the interventions.

Would either of the above methods be appropriate in approaching this problem, or is there a more effective strategy available?